# Is $\frac{\sin(2z)}{e^z-1}$ holomorphic at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Is $f(z)=\frac{\sin(2z)}{e^z-1}$ holomorphic at $z=0$? The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb C$\ $\{0\}$.So it's not holomorphic at $0$?

Comment: Have you take a look at the multiplicity of $z=0$ as zero of both functions? Maybe the Taylor (MacLaurin) expansion could help you

Comment: it has a removable singularity at $0$, so one may define a holomorphic extension of $f$ to $0$

Comment: There is an error in your statement. The domain of $f$ cannot be $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, since $f$ is undefined at every number of the form $2\pi in$ $(n\in\mathbb Z$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes no sense to ask whether a function which is not defined at $0$ is holomorphic there or not. However, it is true that we can extend $f$ to an holomorphic function whoce domain contains $0$. That's so because$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin(2z)}{e^z-1}=2.$$So, $0$ is a removable singularity and you can therefore apply [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem).